# Traefik installation error on GCS: Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:default:default"

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been racking my head on how to set up traefik with GKE. I'm currently getting what I think is an RBAC related error...

```
github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: 

Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: 
ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User system:serviceaccount:default:default" 
cannot list ingresses.extensions at the cluster scope: 
Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:default:default"`
```

Any idea on how to get around this error?

Answer (score 0):

That is an error the GKE IAM authorizer returns when a user is not authorized to do something. In GKE, the RBAC authorizer is then consulted. The fact that you are seeing that error message means both the GKE and RBAC authorizers forbid that user. Make sure you are deploying traefik using the expected service account and have set up an RBAC policy that gives that service account required permissions